# How to save data from jquery datatable to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, local-storage

How can I save data from jquery datatable to browser storage ?
I tried this code:

```
$('#mytable1').dataTable( {
  stateSave: true,
  stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data) )
    },
  stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
    return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ) )
    }
} );
```

But it's not working, when I refresh page - data disappear

Comment: are you sure you are using the same key to retrieve it? We don't know what settings parameter looks like as you have omitted this from the code.

Comment: Hi,  I'm beginner in javascript,  I copied this code from documentation and I don't know.  What I should do?  :-)

Comment: dodaj breakpoint'a na localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data) ) I sprawdz co masz w kluczu

Comment: Hi , @Dawid77 Can put your code jsfiddle so that i can help you out Thanks.